# How to remove a first few words from a txt file using powershell

Tags: powershell

One of the my host.txt file shows a data like below,I want the last word to be exist after trim.

How can I do that ? Can anyone help please ?

| caa3ab95-ecad-46fe-9905-ceac58853ffc | Test-1-my_instance-25ghikbbpip6 |

I want only the name from "**Test-1-my_instance-25ghikbbpip6**"

I tried below methord but didn't work at all

```
$hosts = Get-Content C:\host.txt

foreach ($line in $hosts)
    {
    $split1 = $line.trim("|")
    $split2 = $split1.Split(",")[1]
    echo $split2 >> C:\instance.txt
    }
```

Comment: why don't you split on `|`? why are you trying to split on `,` when strings don't contain commas??

Comment: use $line.Split('|')[2] in your foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Following:

```
$hosts = Get-Content "C:\host.txt"

foreach ($line in $hosts)
    {
        $split1 = $line.trim("|")
        $split2 = $split1.Split("|")[1]
        Write-Output $split2 >> "C:\instance.txt"
    }
```

Will give an output of:

`Test-1-my_instance-25ghikbbpip6`

Example:

```
    PS C:\Windows\system32> 
$hosts = Get-Content "C:\Users\me\Desktop\test.txt"

foreach ($line in $hosts)
    {
        $split1 = $line.trim("|")
        $split2 = $split1.Split("|")[1]
        Write-Output $split2 >> C:\instance.txt
    }

PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-Content C:\instance.txt
 Test-1-my_instance-25ghikbbpip6
```

Comment: why trim? makes zero sense, why save to variable and write-output? write directly to file

Comment: To keep in line with the OP's coding style so he can understand where he went wrong. Feel free to post up an alternative and more concise solution for users to learn.

Comment: Thanks will. I was just trying to sort below line in my text file                         | 6cb33d81-8e8e-4493-8702-a3927a4d3ab3 | bare-11-my_instance-opsm5k6z6d6t        | ACTIVE | -          | 
Running     | glcos01b-private=10.100.11.1, 10.231.224.31  |                       Aftre trim I wanted only the IP address 10.231.224.31 to be my text file but that not worked really.

Comment: I am getting the IP in text file, but getting some error also                              $hostsraw = Get-Content C:\hosts.txt
foreach ($line in $ $hosts)
    {
        $split1 = $line.trim("|")
        $split2 = $split1.Split("|")[1]
        $split3 = $split2.Split(",")[1]
        
        echo $split3 > C:\ipaddress.txt
    }

Comment: Looking at that quickly, your `($line in $ $hosts)` should be `($line in $hosts)` but go ahead and create a new question on the questions page so you can format the question correctly with what your expected outcome will be and what you're currently seeing, with any errors you're encountering.